# Google Translation API

Tags: google-translate

I have text that I would like to translate into Russian. The text has custom tags and has multiple `<BR>` tags. The API behaves oddly with `<BR>` tags. Are there known issues with `<BR>` tags? Is there a way around it or what is the best way to use Google JQuery tranlsation to translate the text?

The text is

```
<INPUTANSWER PARTID='1'>
  <SPAN STYLE="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN>
  Place a <STRONG>90 degree</STRONG> explicit angle constraint to the inside 
  faces of <STRONG>DP-1007:1 </STRONG>and<STRONG>DP-1006:1</STRONG> as shown.</P>
  <P STYLE="MARGIN-LEFT: 0.5in; TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in">
  2.
  <SPAN STYLE="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'"> </SPAN>
  Drive this angle constraint between <STRONG>90 and 100 degrees</STRONG>
  with an <STRONG>increment</STRONG> <STRONG>of 0.125 degrees.</STRONG>
</INPUTANSWER>
```

Comment: Here is the text:
<INPUTANSWER PARTID='1'><SPAN STYLE="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </SPAN>Place a <STRONG>90 degree</STRONG> explicit angle constraint to the inside faces of <STRONG>DP-1007:1 </STRONG>and<STRONG>DP-1006:1</STRONG> as shown.</P> <P STYLE="MARGIN-LEFT: 0.5in; TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in">2.<SPAN STYLE="FONT: 7pt 'Times New Roman'"> </SPAN>Drive this angle constraint between <STRONG>90 and 100 degrees</STRONG> with an <STRONG>increment</STRONG> <STRONG>of 0.125 degrees.</STRONG></INPUTANSWER>

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/). Its the jquery translate project. I've used it before with normal text, never tried markup but quoting their home page

> It also reduces the number of requests by concatenating elements and doesn't send unnecessary html markup still providing access to each element as they've got translated.

If this doesn't work you can always hold on to the original document fragment and just walk it, translate content and replace. I am sure this will work as the API behaved perfectly with plain text.

Answer (score -1):

Find traslator, who would read machine transltions, thats a bad tone. besides completely unclear from English to Russian due complete different language structures. Easier to read in English than auto translated text